# Want to print out DataFrame after applying the pycaret setup changes

Tags: python, pycaret

How to print the data frame after "pycaret setup".That is after applying the one-hot encoder and other changes

Answer (score 0):

`get_config()` can help in general.

For example, in clustering module after `setup()` is run, you can get the transformed data by `get_config('X')`.

Comment: what is `X` here?

Answer (score 0):

just run this exactly in your python script/Jupyter cell: `get_config('X_transformed')` after `setup()` and the dataframe post setup run will return

Comment: Please [edit] this into an answer to the question at the top of this page, according to [answer] - in contrast to an answer to a question in a comment on an existing answer. If you cannot do that please delete the post. Maybe you can turn it into a proposed edit on that existing answer. But an answer post can only be used to answer the question at the top of the page.

Comment: @Yunnosch my intention was to reply to Scope's comment by adding a comment, but I don't have enough reputation to comment. hopefully i made the appropriate revision. if not, please advise. thank you.

Comment: If you still mean this to answer to comment instead of the answer at the top - please deletet this. If you cannot [edit] to make clear that and how this answers the question at the top of the page - please delete this. If you mean this to be any kind of comment - please delete this. Otherwise, please [edit] according to [answer] - and answer to the question at the top of this page, and clearly and obviously so. Maybe you can be a little more verbose and explain how what you propose cause the printing of the data frame after "pycaret setup", after applying the one-hot encoder and other changes.